# hsp/hfp doesn't work on Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS with bluetooth headphones

Tags: bluetooth, headphones

I have bluetooth headphones with microphone. I can connect them to my PC, but when I want to change the sound profile to HSP/HFP they stop working (mic doesn't work and I can only hear static). If I open youtube the video doesn't load. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2):

If it is a Broadcom chip this might help you:

```
lsusb

# Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21e6 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0 [ThinkPad]
```

I could connect the headset before, but just like for you, as soon as I switched to HSP/HFP the mic and audio wouldn't work.

I tried some things. But I'm pretty sure this was the solving step:
Found this link in another article somewhere.

I replaced my BCM firmware file with the one downloaded from plugable (link below). **Make sure that you have a that chip first!** And I'd recommend to do some **backup of the original firmware** files as well.

```
cd /lib/firmware/brcm
# backup original
cp BCM20702A<yourversion>.hcd xxxBCM20702A<yourversion>.hcd
```

https://plugable.com/2014/06/23/plugable-usb-bluetooth-adapter-solving-hfphsp-profile-issues-on-linux/

Then I pretty much followed these instructions, point out that I had to use the name of my original driver. I first missed this and had something saying 'could not find' in

```
dmesg | grep -i blue
```

As soon as you replaced the files shut down your machine (not just reboot) and start it up again. Works for me now =)
I'd love to here if this did the job.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I think I don't have this chip, because it doesn't show up when I type in lsubsb.

Comment: This solved my problem. I went here https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware to get precise firmware for my chip. Thank you sir, you saved my day, I was struggling for hours.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Broadcom BCM20702 on Focal. Following two steps solved the issue for me (Broadcom only!):

1. Download and install the .deb-package from:
   https://github.com/winterheart/broadcom-bt-firmware/releases
2. power off -> power on

@Miles Davis @jenerous: Thanks for the hints!